# dojo js library + jsdoc -> how to document the code?

Tags: dojo, documentation-generation

I'd love to ask you how do the guys developing dojo create the documentation?

From nightly builds you can get the uncompressed js files with all the comments, and I'm sure there is some kind documenting script that will generate some html or xml out of it.

I guess they use jsdoc as this can be found in their utils folder, but I have no idea on how to use it.  jsDoc toolkit uses different `/**commenting**/` notations than the original dojo files.

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all done with a custom PHP parser and Drupal.  If you look in `util/docscripts/README` and `util/jsdoc/INSTALL` you can get all the gory details about how to generate the docs.

It's different than [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) or [JSDoc](http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/) (as youv'e discovered).

FWIW, I'm using [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) as it's much easier to generate static HTML and there's lots of documentation about the tags on the google code page.

Also, just to be clear, I don't develop dojo itself.  I just use it a lot at work.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the "dojo jsdoc" process. There is a parser, written in PHP, which generates xml and/or json of the entirety of listed namespaces (defined in util/docscripts/modules, so you can add your own namespaces. There are basic usage instructions atop the file "generate.php") and a Drupal part called "jsdoc" which installs as a drupal module/plugin/whatever.

The Drupal aspect of it is just Dojo's basic view of this data. A well-crafted XSLT or something to iterate over the json and produce html would work just the same, though neither of these are provided by default (would love a contribution!). I shy away from the Drupal bit myself, though it has been running on api.dojotoolkit.org for some time now.

The doc parser is exposed so that you may use its inspection capabilities to write your own custom output as well. I use it to generate the Komodo .cix code completion in a [rather sloppy] PHP file util/docscripts/makeCix.php, which dumps information as found into an XML doc crafted to match the spec there. This could be modified to generate any kind of output you chose with a little finagling.

The doc syntax is all defined on the style guideline page:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/developer/styleguide.html